# How To Keep The Matching Words From Blob In Php

Tags: php, blob

**Condition :**
(PHP programming language)

I'm designing a website that stores some lyrics (song's of course).
Every lyric stored in BLOB data type.

---

**Problem :**

I'm going to make a "quick lyric search" menu. So, the users just type some words in available textarea (for example named = "txt_lyric"), then they will get the results.

The problem is, how to get a few lines of lyrics from my database (BLOB datatype) that matched from "quick lyric search" menu.

PS : i have already get the matching lyrics with "like" query (the code below), but actually i wanted to get some lines from that BLOB to show the users the matching line.

```
//.....    
elseif(isset($_POST[btn_lyric]))
    {
        $quer=$_POST[txt_lyric];
        $SQL="select * from musik where LOWER(CONVERT(lirik USING latin1)) like '%".$quer."%' order by tanggal_upload desc";
        $category="matching lyric";
        $keywords="$_POST[txt_lyric]";
    }
//.....
```

I just wanted the line that matched "$_POST[txt_lyric]". All i got is just a word.

---

This images may be helpful to illustrate my problem :
[image: Here it is]

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using BLOBs for this?  Use TEXT.

Comment: As a clarification of the reasoning here.  There's "no difference" in the storage capacity of BLOB and TEXT (and, in fact, their documentation page is the same one), but BLOB is stored as binary (great for images, audio, etc.) while TEXT is stored as ASCII characters.  You (the OP) want to do text manipulations, so you should be using TEXT.  See [the blob/text manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) for more details.

Comment: Yap, @rockerest was true. And actually i have no problem with the data type though.
The real problem is, how could i get some sentence from the matching words.